# Application Loader: "No eligible applications were found."

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect

We have already submitted an application for App Store (and it's live). To upload the updates, we were trying "Application Loader". But getting following error:

"No eligible applications were found."
"To add an application witg Application Loader, you must first log in to iTunes Connect and provide information about application you will be adding."

Not sure what needs to be done.

Thanks in advance,

Sunil

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to go into iTunes connect and go into the Manage Applications sections. From there you should select your currently live App to view it's details, and then hit the "Add new version" button.

You should then fill out the necessary meta data. At this point you can change the apps name as it appears in the app store or change its keywords, screenshots etc.

Then once that is done and submitted, you should click the ready to upload binary button near the top right of the page. You'll be asked the usual questions about adding or modifying encryption and a new question regarding iCloud and legal issues. Answer according to your particular situation and carry on. Your app should now be in the "waiting for upload" state.

Once your update is in this state, you can use Application Loader or Xcode's Organiser to upload the binary for the update.

Xcode and application loader now perform some standard checks on your app to ensure it conforms to the guidelines. Once this is done you're app should transition to the "waiting for review" stage and that's all you need to do.

Comment: Thanks Jasarien. I will try it out get back to you ASAP.

Comment: Also I found that iTunes Connect does not accept uploads in the 'Prepare for upload' stage. You need to wait for the 'Waiting For Upload' stage. I don't know if this also goes for updates, it does for submitting a new app.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was mistaken here. When the stage is 'Prepare for Upload' that means that you still need to complete the app metadata section. In particular, take heed of the button in the right bottom corner of the entry form labeled 'Ready to upload binary'. You need to click that and confirm in the final screen that your app does (not) use encryption. 
This blog has an insightful diagram outlining the process (and making me want to purchase OmniGraffle): http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/8/31/itunes-connect-app-status.html

Comment: The terminology has changed to 'Add new version' instead of 'Update Application' but your answer helped a lot.

Answer (score 12):

Go to the Window menue of Application Loader, then choose "Run Setup Wizard..."

Comment: Run Setup Wizard worked great. I was getting the "No eligible applications were found" for an entire day and had no idea where I could change my credentials for iTunes Connect. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This problem normally occurs to the updated versions of the applications. To Resolve the problem Goto itunesconnect.apple.com , Login with your credentials. Click on the updated version icon in the itunesconnect then on the top right you will find the  Ready to upload binary button. Clicking on the button prompts  questions:

> 1. ***Have you added or made changes to encryption features since you last uploaded a binary for this product?   YES/NO***
>
> ***Are you updating this app because of a legal issue? YES/NO***

select your  choice from those radio buttons then hit done. The problem is Resolved now.